# Use string variable as a member of resources

Tags: windows, vb.net, member

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub HomeButtonHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAddClass.MouseEnter, BtnEditClass.MouseEnter, BtnViewClass.MouseEnter
    Dim Name As String = sender.Image & "Hover"
    sender.Image = My.Resources.Name
End Sub
```

In my resources I have, for example. BtnAddClass.png and BtnAddClassHover.png

I wish to append 'Hover' onto the end of the sender name and then retrieve the correct resource for the image. Select case won't work as I have many buttons, I have only include 3 in the example.

Comment: What is a typical `sender.Image`? Is it "BtnAddClass.png" and you want to change this to "BtnAddClassHover.png" ?

Comment: @AndyG, yes the typical image is BtnAddClass.png, and I will then create another function to revert back to BtnAddClass.png from BtnAddClassHover.png on MouseLeave

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways, but here is a simplistic approach:

```
Dim Name As String = sender.Image
Name = Name.Replace(".png", "Hover.png")
```

You cannot then use `My.Resources.Name` though, it's probably:

```
My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(Name)
```

But the object name (of a resource) doesn't include the extension "png", so you probably need:

```
Name = Name.Replace(".png", "Hover")
sender.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(Name)
```

Comment: "GetObject is not a member of Resources", any ideas?

Comment: Still no luck, now it says "Conversion from type 'Bitmap' to type 'String' is not valid.'

Comment: You should tell us which line the error refers to. However, I'm guessing you need `Dim Name As String = sender.Image.toString`. If not, retype the line and look through what appears after `Image.`, perhaps Name or FileName.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this ..

```
Private Sub HomeButtonHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAddClass.MouseEnter, BtnEditClass.MouseEnter, BtnViewClass.MouseEnter
    Dim btn As Button = CType(Sender,Button)
    Dim Name As String = btn.Image.ToString & "Hover"
    btn.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(Name)
End Sub
```